# SQL query or procedure with distinct and comma-separated values for each distinct row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
218 4   AudioVerse     https://www.audioverse.org/english/podcasts/latest   Latest      NULL    2012-03-29 15:32:44.287
222 7   TPB            http://rss.thepiratebay.se/0             Alt     NULL    2012-03-31 17:55:49.223
223 7   EZTV           http://www.ezrss.it/feed/                Alt     NULL    2012-03-31 17:56:41.573
226 11  The Piratebay  http://rss.thepiratebay.se/100               Audio Only  NULL    2012-04-04 14:57:45.377
227 11  The Piratebay  http://rss.thepiratebay.se/200               Video Only  NULL    2012-04-04 14:58:04.650
229 15  ThePirateBay   http://rss.thepiratebay.se/200                       NULL    2012-04-06 22:40:12.730
230 14  The Pirate Bay http://rss.thepiratebay.se/0                     NULL    2012-04-08 00:59:13.217
232 14  AudioVerse     https://www.audioverse.org/english/podcasts/latest           NULL    2012-04-08 01:03:22.787
233 14  EZTV           http://www.ezrss.it/feed/                        NULL    2012-04-08 01:20:55.860
234 17  Twit           http://twit.tv/node/feed                     NULL    2012-04-13 18:59:23.037
235 17  Diggnation     http://revision3.com/diggnation/feed/MP4-Large       Video Large NULL    2012-04-13 19:01:52.817
```

I want a query or stored procedure to return a table that returns distinct, AND a column with which id's that has this url in common, (The second id column (4,7,11,15,14,17) is the id's in question) in comma-separated form like this:

```
http://rss.thepiratebay.se/0    3   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
http://rss.thepiratebay.se/200  2   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
http://www.ezrss.it/feed/   2   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
https://www.audioverse.org/english/podcasts/latest  2   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
http://revision3.com/diggnation/feed/MP4-Large  1   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
http://twit.tv/node/feed    1   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
http://rss.thepiratebay.se/100  1   4,5,7,7,11,11,15,14,14,14,17,17
```

Here the first column is the distinct url, the next is how many times the url is present (differs from the main table above, but you get the point), and a comma-separated string of which id's that these urls has in common.

The comma-separated string in this case is not correct.

The queries I used to create this table is:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + cast(userid as varchar)
FROM sites

select url, COUNT(*), (@listStr)
from sites
group by url
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

The question I present to you is: how to do this, and which way (if there is more than one) is most efficient?

Any help would be appreciated. I could do this in C# code, but I'd much rather have it in either a stored procedure, or a query, which ever is easiest, and/or faster :P

Answer (score 1):

I use the coalesce method. I have found that the resulting concatenated string depends on whether the string was declared with a value prior to using COALESCE. The following script demonstrates this:

```
DECLARE @Mystring nvarchar( 500 ); --declare but do not set inital value

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable( id int IDENTITY(1 , 1) PRIMARY KEY , name nvarchar( 40 ));

INSERT INTO mytable( name )
VALUES( 'Peter' ) , ( 'Paul' ) ,( 'Mary' );

SELECT @Mystring = COALESCE( @Mystring + ',' , '' ) + name
  FROM dbo.mytable
  ORDER BY id;

PRINT @Mystring; -- will print 'Peter,Paul,Mary' with no leading comma

SET @Mystring = ''; --now set to initial empty string
SELECT @Mystring = COALESCE( @Mystring + ',' , '' ) + name
  FROM dbo.mytable
  ORDER BY id;

PRINT @Mystring; --will print ',Peter,Paul,Mary' ie with leading comma
```

I don't know why tsql does this (I am using 2008 R2 Express) but it is worth being aware of. I now initialise string variables as empty strings and use the SUBSTRING() function to remove the leading delimiter to ensure consistent behaviour.

I am quite new to tsql so apologies if this is old hat stuff but I didn't find it covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select url, count(*), group_concat(userid) 
from sites
group by url
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: What is group_concat? i am using microsoft's sql, not mysql.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen: Then, you should add a tag in your question. Either `[SQL-Server]` or `[MS-Access]` or whatever that "microsoft sql" means.

Comment: Ah. To bad, cause `group_concat()` would give you precisely what you want.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: @barsju: It was kind of evident though. MySQL has neither `VARCHAR(MAX)` nor uses `+` for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

@Bjørn Øyvind Halvorsen

This question is relately OLD, but came across it and thought of shedding some light on it..

--- create table

create table test_kin (id int, location varchar(max), url varchar(max))
go

--- insert some values

insert into test_kin values (4   ,'AudioVerse'     ,'https://www.audioverse.org/english/podcasts/latest')
insert into test_kin values (7   ,'TPB'            ,'http://rss.thepiratebay.se/0')
insert into test_kin values (7   ,'EZTV'           ,'http://www.ezrss.it/feed/')
insert into test_kin values (11  ,'The Piratebay'  ,'http://rss.thepiratebay.se/100')
insert into test_kin values (11  ,'The Piratebay'  ,'http://rss.thepiratebay.se/200')
insert into test_kin values (15  ,'ThePirateBay'   ,'http://rss.thepiratebay.se/200')
insert into test_kin values (14  ,'The Pirate Bay' ,'http://rss.thepiratebay.se/0')
insert into test_kin values (14  ,'AudioVerse'     ,'https://www.audioverse.org/english/podcasts/latest')
insert into test_kin values (14  ,'EZTV'           ,'http://www.ezrss.it/feed/')
insert into test_kin values (17  ,'Twit'           ,'http://twit.tv/node/feed')
insert into test_kin values (17  ,'Diggnation'     ,'http://revision3.com/diggnation/feed/MP4-Large')

--- Query to produce results

```
select distinct url
,count(*) as ID
,stuff((
        select ',' + cast([id] as varchar(max))
        from test_kin
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') as Result
```

from test_kin
group by url
order by ID

HTH,
Kin

Comment: How does the query find the distinct url? I think we need to specify from which table, and when then using distinct we need a group by, and when using group by, we need to provide both url field, count, and the xml path thing... i might have missunderstood, but when i test this query i get: "Invalid column name 'url'"

Comment: Some how the code is not formatted correctly ... there is a from clause as below:
---- code start --------
select distinct url
,count(*) as ID
,stuff((
        select ',' + cast([id] as varchar(max))
        from test_kin
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') as Result
from test_kin group by url order by ID
---- code end --------
I have tested it on SQLServer 2008 R2 and it works fine. This will give you a start on what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Ah.. my bad.. sorry (if you add some spaces behind from, group and order they will be formatted correctly), and the query returns a result that is not correct. the same as the query i have placed in my question on the top.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting ... Can you shed some more light on what your are trying to achive .. Probably something like -- create table , some insert statements , and expected results.

Pretty Sure that using the stuff and for xml path .. that can be achieved.